# Use LDAP to authenticate users of a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ldap

Is it possible to use LDAP (*not* Active Directory) to authenticate users on a MS SQL Server database. We have business users who have SQL user accounts on the database, and want to switch that to an LDAP server (specifically, JumpCloud).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you consider this:

1. Each user has a local machine user account on both the server and the client
2. The local machine user account names on the server and the client match exactly - case, spaces, characters (handle the accounts with jumpcloud agent).
3. The passwords for the local machine account on the server and client match exactly - case, spaces, characters (set the passwords from jumpcloud)
4. Create permissions of local windows users on each sql database you will need to access (On SQL Management studio, expand the database, security, users, right click and add user of type windows user, browse on user name ..., type the username, check name and confirm it)

To have a better idea you can check https://jumpcloud.com/blog/managing-shared-ntfs-folders-local-accounts/